# how to adapt drag drop Formbuilder to Meteor

Tags: meteor, formbuilder

i'm trying to adapt http://bootsnipp.com/forms and  http://dobtco.github.io/formbuilder/  to Meteor.
Meteor seems to be strugglinh with Html template files of both of these FormBuilders.
any pointers on how i can adapt one these to my MeteorJs application ?

Comment: Were you able to find one?

Answer (score 2):

I'm looking for the same integration. If you could find any solution please write it down here.

By the time, not the drag&drop but kind of dynamic form can be created through 
https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform

fyi